# Best way to convert iPhone 3-D game code to run on Android devices?

Tags: iphone, android, opengl-es, android-ndk

I need to convert our existing iPhone 3-D action game code to run on
Android. Recently, I have developed 2-D game on Android platform and
now I am moving towards 3-D. These days I am exploring the options to
convert iPhone/iPad & Symbian code to run on Android devices.

Should I write the entire code of iPhone 3-D game(previously written
in Objective C using OpenGL ES) from scratch in Java using OpenGL
apis, once again?

I have also successfully installed and studied samples of  Android
NDK(specially San Angles sample code) as well. I am also looking for 3-
D game using OpenGL example in Android as well.

Is the use of Android NDK is recommended in order to convert iPhone
code on Android platform or I should code in Java?

I am looking forward for piece of suggestions from your side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well that would be a hard ride...
If the Objective C code is clean and minimalistic it should be possible to do crosscompilation with an apropriate GCC with medium adaption.
As Android ties to Java, often C wrappers for Java are needed to exploit system API features. Usually Java developers experience the other way round... Fortunately, OpenGL ES is natively available to C code.